# How to keep file timestamp?

Tags: windows, files, time, copy

When I copy a file from a PC to an other, the copy doesn't have the same timestamp as the source.
I have the same probleme using either copy/paste or xcopy.
The source PC runs Win2003 and the destination one WinXP, they have the same setup (time wise).

How could I prevent that from happening ? or fix it afterwards ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy) Should do this for you by default.
It is also much faster and more robust then a normal copy.
It can be a pain to get the commands right.

Full documentation can be found [Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28WS.10%29.aspx)
Tt can be downloaded from [Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd&displaylang=en)

Comment: That did work, thanks. I still don't know why tough.